# Difference between physical and virtual keys

Tags: windows-server-2008

I am a member of MAPS (Microsoft Action Pack) and for Windows Server 2008 they have two sets of keys - Physical and Virtual. Can anyone tell me the difference between the two?

I am assuming Virtual is for using in Virtual Machines but this is just a guess.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That guess is correct. Physical is for a traditional installation, Virtual is for use in a VM.

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949748/en-us), the Virtual Key allows you to change settings of the virtual machines and move the virtual machines across virtual environment, with out to loose the activation.

Additonally, you can run multiple instances of teh virtual machines activated with virtual keys (is depending on version, e.g. enterprise can run 4 instances).